# Relationship between scaling up rocket, adding more engines and pressure inside tanks, feedlines

Tags: rockets, pressure, tanks

So can anybody say, what is relationship between scaling up rocket ( more payload to orbit ) adding more engines and pressure inside rocket tanks, feedlines. What is standard pressure inside F9R 1st tanks, versus much larger Saturn V 1st tanks. If you want add 5,10,20 F1 engines on Saturn V 1st, which should result in much more payload to orbit, how will this impact pressure inside tanks, feedlines ? Or will it only impact tanks size and volume. I don't want the question to be too broad so I asked only about RP-1, but If there is difference with hydrogen or liquid methane, you can mentioned it.

Comment: After reading I slept on it, woke up, and read this again. I still can't understand what kind of answer you are looking for. Do you think you could add a sentence or two describing more clearly exactly what it is you'd like an answer to provide? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, do you know what is standard pressure inside F9R 1st stage tanks vs in past Saturn V first stage tanks (both use kerosene). If you want scale up Saturn V from 130 ton to LEO rocket to 300-500 ton to LEO rocket, do you must just scale up rocket with bigger tanks, more fuel in it or you must also add many engines. Will than this scaled up Saturn V with bigger tanks, more fuel and more engines have the same or higher pressure inside tanks, feedlines. Will there be some difference when you use hydrogen, liquid methane. Hope you don't slept on this again.